# themoviedb JSON API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jsonp

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be simple. Get the input of a text field and search the themoviedb.org database for it via the API.

I'm using jQuery and the themoviedb.org APIv3, which supports JSONP. All I get, though, is this response:

`{"status_code":6,"status_message":"Invalid id - The pre-requisite id is invalid or not found"}`

That doesn't really tell me a lot. ID of what?

Things I know:

- I have the right API key
- The search button is submitting and getting the value of the input correctly

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/srdHD/1/), and here's the [API documentation](http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/search-movies) about searching movies. Also, check out [this version](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#search) of the API docs. I think it has to do with the query params.

Really, I have no idea what I'm doing with JSON, so I'm hoping this will be a representative example that will help me understand it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need the correct number of query string parameters. The required paramaters are `query` and `api_key`. I found these requirements here http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fsearch%2Fmovie. Give this a try instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
        mode = 'search/movie?query=',
        input,
        movieName,
        key = '&api_key=470fd2ec8853e25d2f8d86f685d2270e';

    $('button').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + mode + input + key,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'testing',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                console.dir(json);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/srdHD/3/

**Note:** *Since thats most likely your **REAL** api key I would suggest requesting a new one!*

Comment: what is filling in input variable.

Answer (score 5):

The URL you use is not correct, your examples generates the following request:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/MOVIENAME?api_key=APIKEY
```

but according to the API documentation it should look like this:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=APIKEY&query=MOVIENAME
```

I have forked and updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/202A/g73NQ/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Need the correct number of query parameters. The required paramaters are query and api_key

If you are getting error on this by urlencode or decodeing please check your url at [urlencode.in](http://urlencode.in) or [urldecode.in](http://urldecode.in)