# async false with JSON-call not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, api, asynchronous

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm unable to reassign the variable poster_path with the poster-path fetched in the JSON-call. Now what surprises me is that I've tried to it ***async to false***. And it didn't work.

I've searched through multiple existing answers such as this one ([How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)) but haven't found any solution.

```
function getPoster(id) {
var poster_path = null;

$.getJSON( "https://api.moviedb.org"+id+"?", {async: false}, function( data ) { 
       poster_path = data.poster_path;
    }
}
```

PS: API-call has been shortened intentionally for this example. I know that it works and that it returns the correct data.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152276/themoviedb-json-api-with-jquery

Comment: The 2nd param is data, not options, see docs here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. use $.ajax instead.

Answer (score 1):

the `$.getJSON` function is a shorthand version of the `$.ajax` method. Because it is a shorthand version, it makes certain assumptions and one of them is that the call will be **async**.

If you want this to by a **sync** call *which is not recommended* then you want something like

```
$.ajax({
  'async'           : true,
  'dataType'        : 'json',
  'contentType'     : 'application/json',
  'url'             : 'https://api.moviedb.org'+id+'?',
  'success'         : function (data){ 
                        poster_path = data.poster_path;
                      }
});
```